# Error upgrading symfony 2.8 to 3.0

Tags: php, upgrade, symfony

I'm trying to upgrade symfony 2.8 to 3.0 by changing `"symfony/symfony": "3.0.*"` in composer.json
and running `composer update symfony/symfony --with-dependencies` but it fails with this error:

```
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput' not found in /var/www/html/mahtab_v3/app/console on line 17
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/mahtab_v3/app/console:0
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception


  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                               
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:                                                        
  PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput' not found in /var/www/html/mahtab_v3/app/console on line 17  
  PHP Stack trace:                                                                                                                 
  PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/mahtab_v3/app/console:0                                                                          
  .
```

what is the problem?

Comment: In this cases, I delete the cache folder by myself, and try again to composer update. And if it does not work, I delete my entire local project, and pull a clean repo from my remote.

Comment: I agree with @Aigzy, I'd also suggest removing your vendor folder and clearing the composer cache.

Comment: I tried both deleting cache folder  and entire vendor folder but none of them worked!

Comment: Well, your second error says that the class ArgvInput is missing. I think it is because you need to create a new Symfony 3 project with the symfony.phar. If you just execut composer, it will only update the vendor. But Symfony needs a specific structure to works, not only the vendor files

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes from the fact that the postInstall command runs `app/console` which does not exist in symfony 3. You need to:

- Move app/console to bin/cosole
- Change the composer.json structure also to include:

`{
        "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
        "license": "proprietary",
        "type": "project",
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "": "src/"
            },
            "classmap": [
                "app/AppKernel.php",
                "app/AppCache.php"
            ]
        },
        "autoload-dev": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Tests\": "tests/"
            }
        },
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.3.9",
            "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
            "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
            "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
            "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
            "symfony/assetic-bundle" : "^2.8",
            "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
            "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
            "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
            "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
            "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
            "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
            ...
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
            "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
        },
        "scripts": {
            "symfony-scripts": [
                "Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
                "Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
                "Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
                "Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
                "Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
                "Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
            ],
            "post-install-cmd": [
                "@symfony-scripts"
            ],
            "post-update-cmd": [
                "@symfony-scripts"
            ]
        },
        "extra": {
            "symfony-app-dir": "app",
            "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
            "symfony-var-dir": "var",
            "symfony-web-dir": "web",
            "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
            "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
            "incenteev-parameters": {
                "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
            }
        }
   }`

You can try running just `bin/console cache:clear` afterwards.

There are probably still some things you need to fix (Change the AppKernel class to have the log and cache dirs in var, remove these dirs from app/ and create the var dir, change the code in app.php and app_dev.php, fix all the service ids that are not wrapped in '""' e.g `"@service_id"` and other obsolte configurations that you may have.